# Union step does not work with multiple elements

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

The following query returns a user map with an "injected" property called "questions", it works as expected when `g.V().has()` returns a single user, but not when returns multiple users:

```
  return g.V().has("user", "userId", 1)
      .union(
         __.valueMap().by(__.unfold()),
         __.project('questions').by(
            __.outE('response').valueMap().by(__.unfold()).fold()
         )
      )
      .unfold()
      .group()
      .by(__.select(column.keys))
      .by(__.select(column.values));
```

It works, but when I change the first line to return multiple users:

```
g.V().hasLabel("user").union(....
```

I finish the query calling `.toList()` so I was expecting to get a list of all the users in the same way it works with a single user but instead I still get a single user.
How can I get my query to work for both, multiple users or a single user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Gremlin, you have to think in terms of a stream. The stream contains [traversers](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_the_traverser) which travel through the steps you've written. In your case, with your initial test of:

```
g.V().has("user", "userId", 1)
      .union(
         __.valueMap().by(__.unfold()),
         __.project('questions').by(
            __.outE('response').valueMap().by(__.unfold()).fold()
         )
      )
      .unfold()
      .group()
      .by(__.select(column.keys))
      .by(__.select(column.values))
```

you have one traverser (i.e. `V().has("user", "userId", 1)` produces one user) that flows to the `union()` and is split so that it goes to both `valueMap()` and `project()` both producing `Map` instances. You now have two traversers which are unfolded to a stream and grouped together to one final `Map` traverser.

So with that in mind what changes when you do `hasLabel("user")`? Well, you now have more than one starting traverser which means you will produce two traversers for each of those users when you get to `union()`. They will each be flatted to stream by `unfold()` and then they will just overwrite one another (because they have the same keys) to produce one final `Map`.

You really want to execute your `union()` and follow on operations once per initial "user" vertex traverser. You can tell Gremlin to do that with `map()`:

```
g.V().has("user", "userId", 1)
      .map(
        .union(
           __.valueMap().by(__.unfold()),
           __.project('questions').by(
              __.outE('response').valueMap().by(__.unfold()).fold()
         )
        )
        .unfold()
        .group()
          .by(__.select(column.keys))
          .by(__.select(column.values))
       )
```

Finally, you can simplify your final `by()` modulators as:

```
g.V().has("user", "userId", 1)
      .map(
        .union(
           __.valueMap().by(__.unfold()),
           __.project('questions').by(
              __.outE('response').valueMap().by(__.unfold()).fold()
         )
        )
        .unfold()
        .group()
          .by(keys)
          .by(values)
       )
```

Comment: `.group().by(__.select(column.keys)).by(__.select(column.values))` returns what I need, a list of maps and `.group().by(column.keys).by(column.values)` returns a map with all the properties as arrays containing all the values of all the users, not what I needed, so it's not the same. Other that that your solution works perfectly, thanks again!!! Gremlin is confusing because it seems map() is needed sometimes and sometimes not, depending on the kind of step you are calling.

Comment: oh - sorry - i didn't pick up that subtlety of what you wanted. i tend to feel that confusion about Gremlin is related to confusion about streams which is why i wrote this answer the way that i did. I hope that helps clarify what's happening in your mind. it's not as though the need for `map()` is completely arbitrary - there are reasons to use it and reasons not to and those reasons tie back to the stream oriented nature of the language.